# Method invocation 'notify' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointException'

Tags: android

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(),"M_CH_ID");
    builder.setAutoCancel( true )
            .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.icon_notificacao )
            .setContentTitle( "RPfm 105.3" )
            .setContentText( "Ao Vivo" );
    int id = 1;
    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifyManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Isso é um erro ou apenas um aviso?

Comment: um aviso quando passa o mouse por cime do 'notify'.

Comment: Mais agora na aplicação não tá mais aparecendo a notificação, e antes estava.

Comment: Não, sumiu mesmo a notificação quando inicio, como antes.
Qual sugestão?

Comment: Tente: `if(notifyManager != null) { notifyManager.notify(id, builder.build()); }` para remover o aviso.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou tentar aqui

Comment: deu algum resultado?

Comment: Bom, o aviso sumiu, mais não tá notificando ainda. rsrsrsrs

Comment: Você está usando *Fragment*? Tente substituir `getActivity` por `getApplicationContext()` ou `getContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método `getSystemService` pode retornar `null`.
Ele é declarado da seguinte forma (repare na anotação `@Nullable`):

```
public abstract @Nullable Object getSystemService(@ServiceName @NonNull String name);
```

O que acontece é que a IDE detecta a anotação e mostra um aviso.

```
NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Neste momento, a IDE "entende" que notifyManager pode ser nulo,
// e a seguinte chamada de método poderia lançar um NullPointerException:
notifyManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Pra garantir que você nunca cause um NPE, você pode fazer um *null check*:

```
if(notifyManager != null) {
    notifyManager.notify(id, builder.build());
}
```

Mas na prática, isso só será um problema se você passar um `name` que não existe, ou tentar pegar um service de uma versão do Android posterior à que o dispositivo atual suporta.

---

Você pode simular o comportamento da IDE, criando um método com a anotação `Nullable`:

```
public @Nullable String getFoo() {
    return "1,1";
}
```

E tentar invocar um método do objeto retornado:

```
String foo = getFoo();
foo.split(",");
```

Repare que agora você verá um aviso idêntico ao que você descreveu.